# Table Heading Repeats, sort the name column alphabhetically, put them in localstorage

Tags: reactjs, sorting, local-storage

I have created the following form in react js and want to display its items in the table but the problem is every time I enter the data the heading also repeats but have no idea how to solve it also I want to sort the name column in the table alphabetically and store them in local storage. The code for the table are:
TableList.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { TableContext } from '../../../Context/TableContext'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const TableList = () => {
  const { tables, deleteTable } = useContext(TableContext)
  const [sort, setSort] = useState()
  
  return (
    <div>
      {tables.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          {tables.map((tablee) => (
            <table key={tablee.id} width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <thead>
              <tr>
               <th rowspan = "2">Name</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Email</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Phone Number</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Date Of Birth</th>
               <th colspan = "4">Address</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th>City</th>
               <th>District</th>
               <th>Province</th>
               <th>Country</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{tablee.name}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.email}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.phoneNumber}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.dob}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.city}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.district}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.province}</td>
                  <td>{tablee.country}</td>
                  <td>
                  <Link to={`/edit/${tablee.id}`}>
                    Edit
                  </Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTable(tablee.id)}>Delete</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
               
            </table>
          ))}
        </div>
          
         
       
         
     ) : (
        <p>It seems like no data is entered.</p>
      )
       
      }
      <Link to = "profile">Profiles</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TableList
```

Table.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import AddTable from './Add/AddTable'
import TableList from './Items/TableList'

const Table = () => {
  return (
      <div>
          <AddTable />
          <TableList />
      </div>
  )
}

export default Table

AddTable.jsx
import React from 'react'
import AddForm from './AddForm'

const AddTable = () => {
  return (
      <div>
          <AddForm />
      </div>
  )
}

export default AddTable
```

AddForm.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { TableContext } from "../../../Context/TableContext";

const AddForm = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [dob, setDob] = useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [district, setDistrict] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("Nepal");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const { createTable, tables } = useContext(TableContext);
  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const isValidEmail = (email) => {
    return /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(email);
  };
  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    if (!isValidEmail(e.target.value)) {
      setErrors("Email is invalid.Format is name@example.com");
    } else {
      setErrors(null);
    }
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePhoneNumberChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length < 7) {
      setError("Your numbers should be atleast 7 digits ");
    } else {
      setError(null);
    }
    setPhoneNumber((v) => (e.target.validity.valid ? e.target.value : v));
  };

  const handleDOBChange = (e) => {
    setDob(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCityChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDistrictChange = (e) => {
    setDistrict(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCountryChange = (e) => {
    setCountry(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tablesNew = {
      id: tables.length + 1,
      name,
      email,
      phoneNumber,
      dob,
      city,
      district,
      country,
    };
    createTable(tablesNew);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">
            Name:*{/* *(Star) indicates it is required */}
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            placeholder="Enter your Name.."
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">
            E-mail*{/* *(Star) indicates it is required */}
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            required
            placeholder="name@example.com"
            value={email}
            onChange={handleEmailChange}
          />
          {errors && <p>{errors}</p>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">
            Phone Number:*{/* *(Star) indicates it is required */}
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
            required
            placeholder="Enter your Phone Number"
            value={phoneNumber}
            onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
          />
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="dob">Date Of Birth (DOB):</label>
          <input type="date" value={dob} onChange={handleDOBChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="address">Address:</label>

          <label htmlFor="city">City:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your city.."
            value={city}
            onChange={handleCityChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="district">District:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your district.."
            value={district}
            onChange={handleDistrictChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="province">Province:</label>
          <select defaultValue="province">
            <option value="province" disabled>
              Choose Province
            </option>
            <option value="provinceOne">Province One</option>
            <option value="madeshProvince">Madesh Province</option>
            <option value="bagmatiProvince">Bagmati Province</option>
            <option value="gandakiProvince">Gandaki Province</option>
            <option value="lumbiniProvince">Lumbini Province</option>
            <option value="karnaliProvince">Karnali Province</option>
            <option value="sudhurProvince">Sudhurpaschhim Province</option>
          </select>
          <label htmlFor="country">Country:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Country"
            value={country}
            onChange={handleCountryChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button>Create Table</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddForm;
```

TableContext.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import TableReducers from '../Reducers/TableReducers'
import { CREATE_TABLE, EDIT_TABLE, DELETE_TABLE } from '../Reducers/ReducerTypes'

const initialState = {
    tables: [],
  };
  
export const TableContext = createContext(initialState)
  
const TableProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(TableReducers, initialState);
  
    const createTable = (tablee) => {
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_TABLE,
        payload: tablee,
      });
    };
  
    const editTable = (tablee) => {
      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_TABLE,
        payload: tablee,
      });
    };
  
    const deleteTable = (id) => {
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_TABLE,
        payload: id,
      });
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      
  })

    return (
      <TableContext.Provider
        value={{
          tables: state.tables,
          createTable,
          editTable,
          deleteTable,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </TableContext.Provider>
    );
  };
  
  export default TableProvider;
```

TableReducers.jsx

```
import { CREATE_TABLE, EDIT_TABLE, DELETE_TABLE } from "./ReducerTypes";

const TableReducers = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CREATE_TABLE:
        return {
          ...state,
          tables: [...state.tables, action.payload],
        };
  
      case EDIT_TABLE:
        const updatedTable = action.payload;
  
        const updatedTables = state.tables.map((tablee) => {
          if (tablee.id === updatedTable.id) {
            return updatedTable;
          }
          return tablee;
        });
  
        return {
          ...state,
          tables: updatedTables,
        };
  
      case DELETE_TABLE:
        return {
          ...state,
          tables: state.tables.filter(
            (tablee) => tablee.id !== action.payload
          ),
        };
  
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default TableReducers;
```

ReducerTypes.jsx

```
export const CREATE_TABLE = 'CREATE_TABLE'
export const EDIT_TABLE = 'EDIT_TABLE'
export const DELETE_TABLE = 'DELETE_TABLE'
```

I want the name column to be sorted alphabetically, table heading not be repeated and store them in a local storage.

Answer (score 0):

The header repeats because you have the header inside of the map function.

```
{tables.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          {tables.map((tablee) => (
            <table key={tablee.id} width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <thead>
              <tr>
               <th rowspan = "2">Name</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Email</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Phone Number</th>
               <th rowspan = "2">Date Of Birth</th>
               <th colspan = "4">Address</th>
              </tr>
```

Move the `<table> <thead>...</thead>` outside of the map function. Only map through the table body. That way you have one header with all the repeated table rows below it. Then close the table outside of the map.

Do something like this:

```
const tableRows = dataYouWantToMap.map((i) => {

    return (
        <>
            <tr>
               <td>{i.Name}</td>
               <td>{i.Email}</td>
               <td>{i.Phone}</td>
               <td>{i.DOB}</td>
               <td>{i.Address}</td>
            </tr>
        </>
    );
});
...

        <table aria-describedby="Customer Table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th rowspan = "2">Name</th>
                <th rowspan = "2">Email</th>
                <th rowspan = "2">Phone Number</th>
                <th rowspan = "2">Date Of Birth</th>
                <th colspan = "4">Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {tableRows}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

As far as the sorting and storing, you can do something like this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.Name < b.Name) { return -1; }
    if(a.Name > b.Name) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})

localStorage.setItem('STORAGE_LIST_NAME', JSON.stringify(data));
```

If you want to add a [Sortable Tables](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/sortable-tables-react/) follow this

Comment: Doing this scatters all of the tabledata under name column...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? In the JSX you need the table, head, and table row with all the headers. That way it wont repeat. You only want to map what you need to repeat. So by putting a table row with table down in the map, it should only repeat the <tr>. Make sure you have the same number of <th> as <td>. Can you include a screenshot of what the issue is?

Comment: Thank you this works for heading repeat but I did not understand about sorting namecolumn alphabetically and storing them in localstorage.

Comment: Are you trying to sort them before you display the table? Or are you trying to add a sorting functionality to the table name column? Both are doable, just done differently. If you want to sort the data before storing in localstorage and displaying in the table, do something like what I showed or like this: `tables.sort((a, b) => a.Name.toLowerCase() > b.Name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);` This will run through each item in the tables array and check if one comes before the other alphabetically.

Comment: For localstorage `localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');` would create a new object of 'myCat' and the value would be 'Tom'. This sets the value of the pair identified by key to value, creating a new key/value pair if none existed for key previously.

Comment: I want to sort them after adding it to column where there should be some sorting symbol and it sorts name alphabetically after the symbol is pressed. I understood about the localstorage but have no idea in which folder to use them.